# Tying together multiple socket connections that were initiated from the same instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

If you have multiple transport protocols that start from the same client how would you go about tying their unique ids together? For me, I'm using socket.io and binaryjs. Socket.io will handle the requests and binaryjs when send the responses. I can't seem to figure out how to tie them together though to accomplish this because each protocol has it's own way of determining it's id. So, when I kick off a new client, the instances of each protocol don't have a common identifier. How do you work around this?

client:

```
<script src='/binary.js'></script>
<script src='/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
<script>
    var socket=io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000');
    var client=new BinaryClient('ws://127.0.0.1:3001');
    function doSomething() {
        socket.emit('someEvent',{success:'someData'});
    }
</script>
<input type='submit' value='Submit' onClick='doSomething();'>
```

server:

```
binjsConnections = {}
binjs.on('connection', function(binclient) {
    binjsConnections[binclient] = {client: binclient}
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(ioclient) {

    // process data from io socket
    ioclient.on('someEvent', function(data) {
        // transport results over binjs socket
        binjsConnections[binclient].client.send(data)
    });
});
```

Comment: i would use an off-sides EventEmitter to subscribe to both API's callbacks in one place.

Comment: I'm not really following what you're suggesting I do. Can you elaborate some?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use session cookies. I'm not sure if you're just using http/websockets but if you are you can. Socket.io has examples if you google for "socket.io session authorization".